# Facebook app invite from inside the app

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

i want to make a facebook flash app. Now im trying to make it possible to invite your friends to the app. I want to do this from within actionscript without the user having to leave the app.

The ideal solution would be to make a custom interface show possible invites and then doing some URL request containing the friends id's

Anyone have any idea how to solve this or if its even possible ?

Comment: I just had to do this for my last site, but found it impossible. Our solution was to use an iFrame over the top of the site to load the fb:multi-friend-selector. I found this blog very useful: http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/06/extending-facebookoauthgraph-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FBJSBridge to call JavaScript functions. From within JavaScript you can launch an invite friends dialog that appears over top of flash. This blog post goes into more detail:

http://blog.goltergaul.de/2009/12/facebook-inviting-people-to-your-application-from-within-actionscript/